# MySQL DB multiple data for field

Tags: php, mysql

Maybe I have never searched in the right place but I often wonder what is the best practice to store multiple data in one field and I have never found an answer that I could use.

Let me be more clear with an example.

Let's say I have a "hobbys" field in a `user_table`

When the user signup he want to add `tennis`, `video game`, and `piano` to his profile.

Is it better:

1. To create different fields for every hobby like: `hobby_id_1, hobby_id_2, hobby_id_3`
2. Or create a single field called hobbys and insert data separated with a comma ? hobbys_id => 1,4,5
   (is this solution is actually possible ?)

And then when we want to update those data and add a new hobby for example, how do we do that ?

Any small help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This falls under **many to many** relationship.

For storing many-to-many relationships, an intermediate table that mainly stores the primary keys (IDs) of each relationship is required. In your case,

> users_table(user_id, firstname,...)
>
> hobbies_table(hobby_id, name,...)
>
> users_hobbies_table(id, user_id, hobby_id)

[Here](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html) is a more elaborate explanation.

Comment: Sounds legit and understandable